# A doubt about sizeof

Tags: c++, sizeof

I was trying to do something using sizeof operator in c++.
Please refer to the following code snippet.
http://ideone.com//HgGYB

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *pint = new int[5];
    int temp = sizeof(*pint);
    cout << "Size of the int array is " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output as 5*4 = 20. Surprisingly it comes to 4. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please include the code that you are asking about in the text of your question. Many people don't follow links; external links can go stale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is `pint` is an `int*`. So,

```
sizeof(*pint) == sizeof(int)
```

Compiler doesn't know about `new int[5]`, when it does `sizeof(*pint)` (because `sizeof()` is a **compile time operator**).

[Note: Try the same test with statically declared array, `int pint[5];` and will see the expected result.
Additionally, `sizeof()` returns `size_t` (which is an unsigned value), so it should be:

```
size_t temp = sizeof(...);
```

]

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` which may be larger.

Comment: +1 Suggestion: highlight 'sizeof() is a compile time operator', since it's the real answer to the OP's question.

Comment: so, does it means that we can never check the size of a dynamically allocated array using sizeof operator ? If no, then how to check it

Comment: @Atul, no dynamic allocation cannot be checked with `sizeof()`. For dynamic allocation there is no standard way. You may have to store the size in some variable. (Though there are some platform specific hacks are there, but very unreliable).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically sized arrays lose their size information- the size is only the size of one integer, as `pint` is a pointer to int, and `*pint` is an integer, not an array type of any size.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for C++ to know the size of the array. 
In your case,

```
*pint
```

returns an int, and sizeof(int) is 4 on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

All fine. You ask for the size of an `int` which will be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

pint is a pointer to int that just happens to point to the beginning of an array.  It contains no information about this array.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you the size of what the pointer points to - the first location in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the current case sizeof(*pint) is giving the sizeof(int), so its returning 4 . But, even if you will try sizeof(pint), it will return you the size of a pointer. Which will most probably be 4 if yours is a 32 bit machine else it will be 8, if 64 bit machine.

Now you have asked, why it is not returning 4*5 = 20. Since pint points to an integer array. Yes, pint points to an integer array, but its not an array. The difference is :

1. Array have a fixed size. you can redectare it at all. While pointers can point to any object of any size.

Since sizeof operator is evaluated at compile time, so compiler dont have any way to know at which size of array this pointer is pointing and so cant tell the size of that object  and so it always return only the size of pointer.  now you can understand, why in case of pointers compiler gives size of the pointer (ie space occupied by pointer in memory), but in case of array it gives full size.